# Show that $A=x_0+W$ for some $x_0$ and some $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space.Let $A$ be a finite subset of $V$ with the property that if $c_i$ is a sequence of scalars such that $\sum c_i=1$ and $a_i$ are vectors in $A$ then $\sum a_ic_i\in A$.

Show that $A=x_0+W$ for some $x_0$ and some subspace $W$.

I am not getting any idea on how to construct $W$ .any help will be helpful

Comment: Is $W$ meant to be a subspace?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Are there any conditions on $W$ and $x_0$?  Is there anything stopping you from taking $x_0 = 0$ and $W = A$?

Comment: Actually, there's a larger issue: if $A$ is a finite subset (as per the problem), it can only have one element.  Suppose $A$ contains two distinct vectors $a_1$ and $a_2$; then it must contain the  vectors $\lambda a_1 + (1 - \lambda) a_2$ which are distinct for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and thus must be in $A$ by the stated criteria.  This implies that the only possible $A$ has one element, in which we take $x_0$ to be the sole element of $A$ and $W = \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: $A$ could also be the empty set in which case if $W$ needs to be a subspace the statement is false.

Comment: you are right @PrahladVaidyanathan

Comment: @MarcusM editted my question

Comment: I'm not sure the edit fixes the issue pointed out in the second comment by @MarcusM. Could you provide an example of such an $A$? In my "world", all nonzero subspaces are infinite.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel you're right, unless (and I have no reason to believe this is the case here) the field is finite.  If the field if finite, then this problem might make some sense, except that every subset of $V$ would be finite so specifying it wouldn't make too much sense.